# Switching from Windows shows all files in git as modified

Tags: external-disk, git

I don't know if I should write here or StackOverflow, but I recently switched from Windows to MacOS and plugged in the eHDD which had my website projects on there.
I forgot to push the updated code to git before moving so I wanted to do that now.

The problem is when I open the folder, it shows that every single line is modified and all files are modified.

Is this a permissions issue or something?

The eHDD is formatted as NTFS, but the projects were extracted from a .zip archive

Comment: What does a diff show as the differences?

Comment: @mmmmmm Every single line of every file. Even though there’s literally only 2 files changed. (5 lines max)

Comment: If we can't answer it here a mod can move it over. One thought here though. macOS can read NTFS fine but it can't *write* to it without a 3rd party tool. Don't know if that helps but I thought I'd throw it out just in case...

Comment: OK thought so - my guess is line endings - MS uses CR LF and macOS/Unix just CR. There are many questions re git and line endings. Unfortunately the usual way is have windows git push as LF and most answers seem to work with that ie changing from Unix to Windows is more documented. So I can't provide a quick answer you'll have to do a deeper hunt

Comment: @SteveChambers The files were moved to local drive.

Comment: @mmmmmm I've tried this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62724723/git-in-visual-studio-code-says-file-is-modified-even-when-there-is-no-change but no luck.

Comment: The other way is convert the line endings on the checked out files. On old Unix system dos2unix and unix2dos were common but not there on BigSur Or just do the chnage in the editor most have command to convert the endings

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a duplicate here.

Resolved the issue hard reseting the staged files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41041699/12034488

Which is taken from https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings which explains the issue and the fix.